# Trying to make a rope wrap around a pole using Bezier Curve + Array

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying to wrap a rope around a pole. I am having a lot of difficulty controlling the Bezier curve nicely around. So I tried a different approach. I made one loop only using a Bezier curve (also tried with path and got same result). I then used the array modifier on the Bezier curve to have the curve continue spiraling down. I selected 'Merge' on the array modifier. I now have a constant rope loop spiraling down.
Now I have my rope object follow this Bezier curve, but it will only follow the main loop and not continue down the array. I tried to apply the array modifier but I am forced to convert to mesh so than I don't have a curve to follow anymore. Any ideas for a workaround guys? I'm using 2.93.3 Thanks!

[image: Rope only follows main bezier loop and doesn't continue down the array]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would enable *Add Curve: Extra Objects* in preferences, so that I could add a spiral.  Instead of trying to wrap a Bezier curve around the pole, I would add an Archemedian spiral and set its parameters to match the pole.  Here's an example:

[image: An Archemdian spiral wrapped around a cylinder]

and the parameters that produced the spiral:

[image: parameters for the spiral]

This would work nicely if you have a material that makes the tube look like the rope.

Once I had an approximation I liked, I would hand edit the spiral to make it look less mechanical and use it as the guide.

Some thoughts on the parameters:

The key parameters in this case are *Turns*, *Radius*, and *Height*.

*Radius*: should be just enough larger than the radius of the pole so that the rope will just touch the pole.

*Turns* and *Height*:  These are a little confusing.  *Height* is the height of one turn, while *Turns* is the number of 360 degree loops in the spiral.  You want height to match how tight or loose you want your rope wrapped.  For instance, a height of twice the radius of the rope would give a nice obvious wrap.  Then divide the length of the pole you want to cover by *Height* to determine the number of *Turns*.

Of course, you can then go to the curve's properties and give it a Round bevel, so that the curve itself can be your rope.

[image: Using the Geometry Bevel to make the rope directly from the spiral]

You can find the Bevel property in the spiral's Object Data Properties:

[image: The spiral's Bevel property settings.]

Comment: Wow fantastic I didn't know about the Extra Objects. Thanks for the help.